# Modificar número de decimales con una variable

Tags: java

Digamos que tengo un valor double con varios decimales, y quiero que el usuario elija los decimales con los que se va a mostrar en pantalla, ¿cómo puedo hacer que el double se muestre en pantalla con el número de decimales que esté guardado en una variable? Lo he intentado con string format, con BigDecimal y con BigFormat pero no me permiten poner una variable para establecer los decimales.

Por ejemplo, tengo un double con un valor de 4.16789876

Y en otra variable tengo guardado el número 2 (Aquí es donde el usuario decide el número de decimales que quiere)

En este caso debería de mostrarse en pantalla 4.16 (pero si el usuario ingresa otro número, el resultado deberá mostrarse en pantalla con dicho número de decimales)

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Magus, agrega lo que has intentado y modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask] para que puedas obtener la ayuda deseada en el sitio, también puedes obtener reputación para poder realizar este tipo de preguntas en [chat].Saludos.

Comment: Hola, debería permitirte guardar ese valor en una variable, mostranos algo de código

Comment: Si el tema es mostrar por pantalla, ¿porqué usar números en vez de cadenas de texto? ¿No sería más sencillo convertir el valor flotante a una representación de cadena (`String`) y usar métodos como [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) que sí acepta una variable como parámetro? Me parece que te haría las cosas mas sencillas si lo que vas a hacer es mostrar un valor. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma general de dar formato a un decimal es

```
String.format( "%.2f", numero)
```

donde el `2`es el número de decimales que se desea. El método `format` de la clase `String` recibe como primer argumento un `String` que indica el formato (en el ejemplo `"%.2f"`) por le que podemos hacer lo siguiente

```
double valor = 4.16789876D; 
int numeroDecimales = 4; //valor ingresado por el usuario
String formatoPersonalizado = "%." + numeroDecimales + "f";

System.out.println(String.format(formatoPersonalizado, valor));
```

Salida con `numeroDecimales = 2` es `4,17`

Salida con `numeroDecimales = 4` es `4,1679`